# In Node red messages double quotes are converted to &quot;

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

I am trying to make a calendar app for my iot webapp. I am using node red for that purpose. Whenever I pass the message the double quote gets converted to `&quot;`

```
events = [
    {
        &quot; occ&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
        &quot;first&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
        &quot;sec&quot;: &quot;2&quot;,
        &quot;third&quot;: &quot;2019&quot;,
        &quot;start&quot;: &quot;11&quot;,
        &quot;end&quot;: &quot;12&quot;
    } 

];
```

It becomes as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention what your flow is doing or what nodes you are using, so it is hard to provide a conclusive answer.

I suspect you are using the core Template node to generate that message payload. The Template node uses the mustache syntax which, by default, auto-escapes certain characters to make them HTML-safe. To prevent mustache from doing that, you would use `{{{triple-braces}}}` (rather than the default `{{double-brace}}`. This is described in the sidebar help for the Template node.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is running in the browser you can use this function to convert HTML-Symbols to actual characters:

```
function decodeHtmlChars(instr) {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
    textarea.innerHTML = instr;
    return textarea.value;
}

events = decondeHtmlChars(events[0][0])
```